# Graphics Magick C++ API PNG Output

Tags: c++, graphics, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to write a simply utility that runs through a list of supplied image files, opens them up and checks that the images are either 24bit or 32 bit. If they aren't they are then converted and saved out as such.

I've tried this with slight alterations under ImageMagick and Graphics Magick - the code below is under Graphics Magick. I grabbed the params for saving from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728550/imagemagick-c-api-output-16-bit-grayscale-png)

BTW I'm using Graphics / Image Magick because in other parts of my utility I need to split PSD files and as far as I know Image / Graphics Magick are the only graphics API's that can read / write PSD files, with layers, correctly. (layers bit is important)

But I don't seem to be having any luck.  Any ideas what could be wrong. Anyone doing this successfully? Any better suited API's?

I'm building the latest libs for each.

Cheers,

Martin

```
void
fileProcess( const std::string& pFileName )
{
    Magick::Image img;
    img.read( pFileName );

    if( img.type() != Magick::TrueColorMatteType && 
        img.type() != Magick::TrueColorType )
    {
        Magick::ImageType type = img.type();
        std::cout << "Wrong image type - " << pFileName << "\n";

        img.type(Magick::TrueColorMatteType);
        img.magick( "png" );
        img.defineSet("png:color-type", "6");
        img.defineSet("png:bit-depth", "8");
        img.defineSet("png:format", "png32");
        img.write( pFileName );
    }
}

int 
main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick( *argv );

    std::ifstream fileList( ( "fileList.txt" ) );

    if( !fileList.fail() )
    {
        while( !fileList.eof() )
        {
            std::string imageFileName;
            fileList >> imageFileName;
            if( !imageFileName.empty() )
            {
                fileProcess( imageFileName );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your call to img.write ?

Comment: Cut and paste error! I've amended code accordingly.

Comment: Nope.  The files that are causing issues are all GrayscaleType or BiLevelType if that helps. I'm trying to get all my files in the higher format to be read be another API - Marmalade - which currently doesn't read in grey scale images.

Comment: Your grayscale images are written as 8-bit images instead of 32-bit? What if you also set `depth` to 8 and `type` to 6? (i.e. the non png-specific options)

Comment: Same as before - the only type setting I know of is the one I have above where type is set to Magick::TrueColorMatteType, which is 32bit?  Reducing down seems OK - if I hack the code to re-write all the images out as grey scale ones.  It's just the up scaling to a higher bit depth doesn't seem to work. It seems to optimize as it saves out.